# link Rscript to non-existant directory

Tags: rscript

I am using program which automatically assumes that Rscript is installed in my home directory. Not even it is not, but the directory /home/username/bin does not even exist - so calling /home/username/bin/Rscript results in an error.

However typing "Rscript" works from everywhere. Is there any way how to run Rscript whenever this program calls this non-existent directory? I would rather not change code of the program I am using.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symlink to the real file, using the ln command:

```
ln -s /real/path/to/rscript /home/username/bin/rscript
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting $HOME variable solved this issue.